# Error while installing an app from xcode

Tags: ios, iphone

I built an iPhone app and it works fine on iPhone 5,5S but when i try to install it on an iPhone 4 i get an error :

Could not install application on device, `Error:kAMDIncorrectArchitectureError`

I've checked my project settings and `armv7` is already added.
What could be causing this error ?

Comment: I think if you are supporting armv7s (The 64 bit version) you can't support iPhone 4.

Comment: Are you installing it with iPhone Configuration Utility on Windows?

Comment: Yes, Using iPhone Configuration Utility on Windows.

Comment: Check this link of apple support https://discussions.apple.com/message/22923905#22923905

Comment: My project already has armv7,armv7s,arm64

Comment: Correction to my last comment if you have arm64 it will not run on iPhone 4. Remove arm64 and try again.

Comment: Then how i should support iPhone 5s ?

Comment: Have a read of this http://www.mobinett.com/2013/09/20/ios-7-xcode-5-project-build-settings-for-architectures-and-arm64-support/ Specifically this `"Since the Arm instruction sets are backward compatible, any application compiled for armv7s will also run on the iPhone 5s or the iPhone 5c."` iPhone 5s can support 32 bit but iPhone 4 can't support 64 bit so it's more of what architecture you want to support

Comment: We need to be 100% clear we're talking about removing `arm64` from STANDARD ARCHITECTURE and absolutely not talking about removing it from VALID ARCHITECTURE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below things may be help you.

In your project target settings, make sure you have:

```
Architectures should be: Standard architecture (armv7 armv7s)

Valid architectures: should be arm64 armv7 armv7s (add these three things)


Build Active Architecture Only should be No
```

Also make sure that, clean all the targets and then after build it.

Comment: I want to support iPhone 4,5 and 5S.